# Convert markdown linked .md to .html

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, javascript-marked

I am using [marked cli](https://github.com/markedjs/marked#installation) to convert my markdown file to html file.

I want to convert hyper linked markdown file (.md) to (.html)

Current output:

```
$ echo "[test](./doc/test.md)" | marked
<p><a href="./doc/test.md">test</a></p>
```

Expected output:

```
$ echo "[test](./doc/test.md)" | marked --some-option
<p><a href="./doc/test.html">test</a></p>
```

Is there any option to get the required output.
I can use the marked lib with JavaScript if there is an option in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at marked [documentation](https://marked.js.org/), there isn't any build in way of changing URLs.

---

I'd recommend using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to change every `.md">` to `.html">` like so:

```sh
echo "[test](./doc/test.md)" | marked | sed -e 's/\.md\"\>/.html">/g'
```

Comment: Thanks @0stone0, this is a nice work around. For me this worked `echo "[test](./doc/test.md)" | marked | sed 's/\.md">/.html">/g'`